# Rails 3 + FactoryGirl: NameError: uninitialized constant Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > Factory.define :user do |user|
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 >       user.email                  "user@example.com"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009?>     user.password               "foobar"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010?>     user.password_confirmation  "foobar"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011?>   end
NameError: uninitialized constant Factory
```

My Gemfile:

```
group :test do 
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc4'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Even tough it seems I have everything as it should, I keep getting that error. I also have factories.rb created.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you try in console in development environment. But you add the Factory gem only in test environment.

If you want access to Factory_girl in development use in your Gemfile :

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Or if you want test your Factory launch your console in test environment :

```
rails c test
```

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem on our end, rake spec seemed to be randomly failing with the error uninitialized constant FactoryGirl. The error was random -> coming and going. We went back half a dozen git commits to try and resolve it. In the end it was a silly mistake.

The fundamental problem is RAILS_ENV is set to **development**. It needs to be set to **test** when you run rake spec.

Address by:

1. Making certain that we are running rake spec in the RAILS_ENV **test** environment and its exported/sourced properly. To never confuse our environemnts, we modified zsh $RPROMPT env variable to show the current env.

   export RPROMPT="[%{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}$RAILS_ENV%{$reset_color%}]"
2. Require FactoryGirl in the spec ruby files gave a much better error message. At least rspec  would run vs just fail outright this way when the environment was wrong. We also updated our gemfile to make sure factory_girl_rails and factory_girl were loaded both for development and testing.
3. Now we just run rpsec using the **gem guard** in a dedicated terminal with the proper RAILS_ENV set.

Its one of those gotchas.

We're running Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.9, Rspec 2.12, factory_girl 4.1.

Comment: OMG I forgot I had this set!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this while I was doing the Hartl tutorial.

If you are using "**Spork**" to speed up your tests and it is running in the background when you add the FactoryGirl code, you will need to stop it and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

You should also change Factory.define to FactoryGirl.define, like in this example

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'John Doe'
    date_of_birth { 21.years.ago }
  end
end
```

from the [factory_girl documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)